# Chrome Extension - Is there a way to work around CSRF protection when POSTing with a XMLHttpRequest?

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-chrome-extension

I'm currently working on a chrome extension and would like to use an XMLHttpRequest to POST to a particular website and retrieve the response, but I get a 403 error due to the website's CSRF protection. Is there any way to get around this? I'm thinking of using a python script on a raspberry pi (my extension is purely for personal use) to get around this if I cannot do this purely with Javascript.

Thank you.

Comment: What's the manifest.json's `"permissions"`? Do you perform the request in a content script or the background/popup page script?

Comment: I've included the site in the manifest's permissions. I'm running the request in the content script.

Comment: Ah, I see. In that case, I may try to access the site through a background script instead. Thanks! 

By the way, would you say that there is no simple method for bypassing the CSRF protection through the content script?

Comment: Ah, I was wrong: you can do XHR from the content script to a site declared in "permissions". A probable solution in your case is to open a hidden iframe with that site and perform XHR from the content script that runs within.

Comment: I tried using an iframe, but the site does not allow iframe requests. I think I'll just go with the script idea. I appreciate your help though! I'm more comfortable if I feel that I've exhausted my options, so thank you.

Comment: It's possible to strip X-Frame-Options http header, if that's how the site prevents embedding, you can find examples of doing that with chrome.webRequest.